# Shell command, how to copy newer files in a folder?

Tags: shell

I'm new to shell command.

I want a feature that xcopy do (copy all files from a folder and replace older files):

```
xcopy ../SourceFolder/ TargetFolder/ /D /E /Y
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `/D /E /Y` are, but did you try `cp -f ../SourceFolder/* TargetFolder/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The correct answer for macOS is using `rsync`:

You could try using [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

`rsync -u [source] [destination]`

or

`rsync --update [source] [destination]`

-u, --update skip files that are newer on the receiver

Comment: I tried in terminal and it output : illegal option -- u, I'm using mac os.

Comment: usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_director

Comment: @Yonghui pay attention to the amount of dashes `-` you are using, use **one dash** for **single letter** flags and **two** for a **string parameter**.

Comment: I used only one dash. And I just google and find that mac os's cp is different from Linux's, so sad.

Comment: You could try using `rsync`:

`rsync -u [source] [destination]`